# Formatting commands are not applied to Hebrew text in tables

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

This is a sample code for generating a Word document with a table.
The code works perfectly, but the Hebrew text in the cells isn't affected by the formatting lines like "Bold font" and "Alignments". The same code works fine for English content.

```
    Dim oWord As Word.Application
    Dim oDoc As Word.Document
    Dim oTable As Word.Table


    'Start Word and open the document template.
    oWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
    oDoc = oWord.Documents.Add


    'Insert a 3 x 5 table, fill it with data, and make the first row
    'bold and italic.
    Dim r As Integer, c As Integer
 oTable = oDoc.Tables.Add(oDoc.Bookmarks.Item("\endofdoc").Range, 3, 5)
    oTable.Range.ParagraphFormat.SpaceAfter = 6
    For r = 1 To 3
        For c = 1 To 5
            oTable.Cell(r, c).Range.Text = "שורה " & r & "עמודה " & c
        Next
    Next
    oTable.TableDirection = Word.WdTableDirection.wdTableDirectionRtl
    oTable.Borders.Enable = 1
    oTable.Rows.Item(1).Range.Font.Bold = True
    oTable.Rows.Item(1).Range.Font.Italic = True
    oTable.Rows.Item(1).Range.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = _
      Word.WdParagraphAlignment.wdAlignParagraphCenter
```

Comment: Well, the formatting works fine, here, but the table / text isn't RTL and I can't format the language as Hebrew. I suspect this may have something to do with the languages settings in the UI, but I have little experience in this area. Only thing I can suggest would be to put the RTL command at the top, immediately after inserting the table. You might also try applying language formatting: `oTable.Range.LanguageID = wdHebrew`. Also test whether you're able to apply the formatting in the document as a user.

Comment: Thank you for your replay
I'v just tried to move the commands to the top + language.Still not working !!
I'v tested different PC and Office versions but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try
`oTable.Rows.Item(1).Range.Font.BoldBi`

instead of `oTable.Rows.Item(1).Range.Font.Bold`